# TLS 1.2 - POST to 2 ip addresses?

Tags: ssl, http-post

I need to send information securely (TLS 1.2), via a POST request, to two different external IP addresses simultaneously.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

TLS is a protocol layer on top of TCP. TCP does not support sending to multiple parties at the same time within the same TCP connection and TLS does not add this functionality. This means that you need to implement this yourself, i.e. have multiple connections open to send the data and receive the response.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Steffen.